# fconfigure refuses to set baud rate to 921600

Tags: linux, serial-port, tcl

In `expect` script, I'm trying to replace the `spawn kermit` with a direct access to the serial port/console under Ubuntu 14.04.

The code is fairly simple:

```
set device "/dev/ttyUSB1"
set device_handle [open $device w+]
fconfigure $device_handle -mode "921600,n,8,1" -handshake none
#spawn -open $device_handle
```

My problem is that the Tcl (8.6) or Expect (5.45) refuse to set the baud rate to 921600.

From the `strace` output, I can see that the baud rate is set to 460800 instead (in `TCSETSW` command to `ioctl()`). Like this:

```
$ grep TCSETSW strace.out.*
strace.out.28667:ioctl(6, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_GINFO or TCSETSW, {B460800 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
strace.out.28667:ioctl(6, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_GINFO or TCSETSW, {B460800 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
strace.out.28667:ioctl(6, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_GINFO or TCSETSW, {B460800 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
```

I have tested with lower baud rates - 9600, 115200, 460800 - and Tcl calls the `ioctl()` with the correct baud rates. Only if I try to set the 921600, Tcl sets the 460800 instead. (The `kermit` uses the same `ioctl()` call and sets the correct baudrate.)

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not an expect bug; that's the Tcl side of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have researched the issue, and it appears to be a limitation that is burned into the Tcl core. On the Unix platform, we have a hard coded list of baud rates, and the highest is 460800.

If you are comfortable hacking the Tcl core sources, you can add you own baud rates to the speeds[] array that is populated in unix/tclUnixChan.c (around line 900). We'll be working on getting a more up to date set of speeds into the next release.

--Sean "The Hypnotoad" Woods

Update: The patch is checked in: http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/info/7c1aae5292b3e6cd

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't help me now, but probably in the future. The mess with the baud rates is pretty messy: http://serialconsole.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/serialconsole/sc/sc.c?revision=1.13&view=markup&sortdir=down - line 64 and downwards - all way up to B4000000.